# Summarize upper rows of a previous column - ABC analysis

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I want to make an ABC analysis in Excel 2010 with raw data as follows:

```
client - unit price - bought product - quantity - turnover - % of turnover (per trade)
```

I made a pivot table but can't create a column with the summarized % of turnover.
So that I can draw a chart and show that the biggest client is responsible for x% of the turnover. The biggest two clients are responsible for x% of the turnover and last that my 100 clients are responsible for 100% of the turnover.

I tried to sort the raw data by turnover and sum the upper values "% of turnover" in a new column. But it won't work, due to the repeatedly trade of one client.

Comment: Did you try sum of % of turnover by client? And then, just filter the rows by column sum of % of turnover (from z to a)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may never know, but I suspect what OP may have wanted is a column (here Sum of Sales) where values are Show Values As % Running Total in Base field: (here) Client:

[image: SO20589288 example]